# Docker container with ubuntu 16.04 add-apt-repository using groovy instead of xenial

Tags: ppa, repository, docker

I have a problem when adding a ppa repository in my docker container.
My ubuntu version in the container is 16.04 that supposed to be `xenial`, but when I added a ppa repository using `add-apt-repository` it's using `groovy`. The problem is, bitcoin ppa repository isn't available yet on `groovy` release.
How to fix this problem ?

Here my Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
FROM node:12.18.1

RUN apt update && apt dist-upgrade -y
RUN apt install software-properties-common -y
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:bitcoin/bitcoin
RUN apt update
```

This is the errors output :

```
Step 5/19 : RUN add-apt-repository ppa:bitcoin/bitcoin
 ---> Running in af0bb3a110cf
 NOT MAINTAINED. The OS-library linking packages here had a series of issues.

PLEASE DOWNLOAD DIRECTLY FROM bitcoincore.org (and verify the signatures of said files).

IF YOU WANT AUTO-UPDATES, please see the officially-maintained snap package -
https://github.com/bitcoin-core/packaging/tree/master/snap
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~bitcoin/+archive/ubuntu/bitcoin
gpg: keybox '/tmp/tmpq1hxj8km/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: key D46F45428842CE5E: 3 signatures not checked due to missing keys
gpg: /tmp/tmpq1hxj8km/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key D46F45428842CE5E: public key "Launchpad PPA for Bitcoin" imported
gpg: no ultimately trusted keys found
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1
Warning: apt-key output should not be parsed (stdout is not a terminal)
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
Removing intermediate container af0bb3a110cf
 ---> 2949a066b51f
Step 6/19 : RUN apt update
 ---> Running in 2a3109f824ca

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

Get:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease [94.3 kB]
Ign:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease
Get:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease [93.6 kB]
Get:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release [118 kB]
Get:5 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages [529 kB]
Get:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main amd64 Packages [28.2 kB]
Get:7 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release.gpg [2410 B]
Get:8 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages [7083 kB]
Ign:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/bitcoin/bitcoin/ubuntu groovy InRelease
Err:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/bitcoin/bitcoin/ubuntu groovy Release
  404  Not Found
Reading package lists...
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/bitcoin/bitcoin/ubuntu groovy Release' does not have a Release file.
The command '/bin/sh -c apt update' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

Comment: The Ubuntu 16.04 docker image shouldn't have Debian Stretch repository in the first place. Run `sudo docker run -it ubuntu:16.04 /bin/bash` and check the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`.

Comment: What exactly do you think `FROM node:12.18.1` does?

Comment: You can download it from the ```bitcoincore.org``` website : ```wget https://bitcoincore.org/bin/bitcoin-core-0.20.0/bitcoin-0.20.0-x86_64-linux-gnu.tar.gz ``` then use **gunzip** to extract it and then **tar xvf** to **untar** it. Then the binary to run is **bin/bitcoin-cli**.

Comment: Expanding [@muru's comment](https://askubuntu.com/posts/comments/2116489): According to [node - Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/node), "*Some of these tags may have names like buster, jessie, or stretch in them. These are the suite code names for releases of Debian and indicate which release the image is based on.*". So you're *actually* running Node on top of Debian not Ubuntu. You can confirm that by running `sudo docker run -it node:12.18.1 /bin/bash` and then `cat /etc/os-release`.

Answer (score 1):

According to [node - Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/node),

> ... Some of these tags may have names like buster, jessie, or stretch in them. These are the suite code names for releases of Debian and indicate which release the image is based on.

So you're actually running Node on top of Debian not Ubuntu. You can confirm that by running `sudo docker run -it node:12.18.1 /bin/bash` and then `cat /etc/os-release`.

The repositories and packages you were trying to install were actually installed in Debian since `RUN` instructions were written immediately after `FROM node:12.18.1`. To run add the repository in Ubuntu image, shift the `RUN` instructions beneath `FROM ubuntu:16.04`, i.e.,

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN apt update && apt dist-upgrade -y
RUN apt install software-properties-common -y
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:bitcoin/bitcoin
RUN apt update

FROM node:12.18.1
```

**Related Documentation:** [Dockerfile reference | Docker Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/)

Answer (score 0):

Although not related specifically to Docker or ubuntu PPAs or the weird **debian** repositories in your `apt update` output from ubuntu 16.04 , you can download the Distro-independent version from the [bitcoincore.org](https://bitcoincore.org/en/download/) website.For example you can do this in your docker container :

```
wget https://bitcoincore.org/bin/bitcoin-core-0.20.0/bitcoin-0.20.0-x86_64-linux-gnu.tar.gz
gunzip bitcoin-0.20.0-x86_64-linux-gnu.tar.gz
tar xvf bitcoin-0.20.0-x86_64-linux-gnu.tar
cd bitcoin-0.20.0/bin
./bitcoin-cli "whatever-argument"
```